# Create new Pipfile.lock with old package versions

Tags: python, docker, pip, pipenv, pipfile

I have a Docker container where `pipenv install --system --dev --skip-lock` was used to install packages from a Pipfile (some weeks ago). Unfortunately there is no Pipfile.lock, so if I rebuild the Docker image now it uses different versions of the dependencies. Therefore I want to create a Pipfile.lock now, so that in the future we use known versions of all dependencies. But I fail to generate a Pipfile.lock with the exact versions that are installed in the container!

If I run `pipenv lock` it creates a Pipfile.lock which contains the latest versions of the dependencies, rather than the old versions that are installed in the old Docker image.
If I run `pipenv lock --keep-outdated` it complains `ERROR:: Pipfile.lock must exist to use --keep-outdated!`.
If I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt; pipenv install -r requirements.txt` it fails because the Docker image also contains some Python packages that were installed from other sources and which apparently cannot be installed with pipenv.

How can I create a Pipfile.lock that contains exactly the dependency versions that are installed in the Docker container? It seems to be a simple thing (just write the Pipfile.lock as done by `pipenv lock`, but don't try to update first); but I can't seem to find the correct command.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure it'll be easy to reproduce the exact same environment – so I'd ask if it's worth it to pursue that, or just create a working lockfile now.